# Spark: Persisting a dataframe within a function

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, persist

I'm trying to reuse the dataframe by persisting it within a function.

```
def run() {
  val df1 = getdf1(spark: SparkSession)
  val df2 = getdf2(spark:SparkSession, df1)
}

def getdf1(spark: SparkSession): DataFrame {
  val sqltxt = "select * from emp"
  val df1 = spark.sql(sqltxt)
  df1.persist
  spark.sql("SET spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet=false")
  df1.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet("/user/user1/emp")
  df1
}

def getdf2(spark: SparkSession, df1: DataFrame): DataFrame {
   // perform some operations
}
```

But, when getdf2 is executing it is performing all operations again. Not sure, if I'm doing anything wrong here. Please help me understand above scenario. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I remember that in scala, when you pass a function as parameters, the function(in this scenario, it is df1) will be executed every time when you call getdf2. Whenever you call getdf1, all the statement in getdf1 was executed again. That's the reason why you see the same operations again.

Read Chapter 5 First-Class Functions of <>

Comment: I am not passing function as a parameter but I am capturing DataFrame returned by getdf1() function in "df1" and passing it to getdf2() function as an argument. Let me know, if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Actually you are. df1 is a function literal,if you don't want to the same operation again, try to put df1 as a global variable or something like that